# Bathtub Surround Wall

Tags: bathroom, walls

We have a rental condo in Dallas TX which has a second bathroom with a bathtub surrounded on 3 sides by ceramic-tile walls. One of the side wall had to be demolished recently to repair the plumbing behind it. (*The pipe has been repaired.*)

To replace the broken tiled-wall  we have to replace the other two in order to make them uniform. Our goal is to have a nice-looking bathroom yet at low cost, as it is only a second bathroom which tenants rarely use. I am thinking about replacing them with some kind of water-resistant panel boards.

My friend forwarded this anonymous picture (*below*) which show a great-looking panel board, solid thick, but he could not identify its name. It was understood that the wall was installed by individual handyman, the material can be readily found in retail stores.

What is this material?  -  (*Wilsonart, laminate,  Formica?*)

[image]

Comment: This looks like a cultured stone product (manufactured panel product). These panels do not fit your "low cost" criteria... tile is cheaper.

Comment: My mother had a similar product, looked like a Corian type product such as that used for countertops. ??

Comment: Thank you to both Jimmy Fix-it and Alaska Man.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Swan Solid surface shower wall panel and it usually isn't a stock item and has to be ordered. It comes in many colors and patterns many that mimic the look of stone, concrete and tile. Great low maintenance product for a good rental.

Comment: I recommend a "tub cove". This is a piece of laminate bent precisely to fit the three walls of your tub/shower or shower. It is trimmed out with metal trim. The best thing is that it is cheap, cleans up with a squeegee and never needs regrouting. I love mine. Yours can look like granite! See www.tubcove.com or similar

Comment: @Rich - Thank you for your information. Is the website SwanStone.com?

Comment: @DAS - Thank you for your information. But the company is localized only around Seattle area, whereas I am in Dallas. Am I not correct? Let me know. Thank you again.

Comment: I get their product on the east coast. Their website states that Apex supply and Economy Supply in Dallas are dealers. They are also available online but the samples there don't look like the actual samples chips at the store. Also says Home depot and Lowes but I've never seen any in their stores but could probably be ordered. You should be able to get the company to ship you a sample chip set to make the choice.

Comment: @A.Magnus Yes that is the site the solid surface colors are here. https://swanstone.com/en/collections-and-finishes/materials-and-finishes/finishes    
  I've seen the granites and they're quality for around a grand.